# Checking for Duplicates in an Array Backwards

Tags: java

This is the same person who had trouble with the last array problem just one or two days ago.
We've a new assignment which asks us to find and replace duplicates in an array of randomly generated numbers. I wrote a code and sent it to my teacher for feedback; she responded with this solution:

> So, take the first random num and store into the first slot (this can be done before the loop).  Then, start a loop that creates the second random num and tests backwards to see if there are duplicates from the ones already stored.  So, a backwards loops that tests for duplicates and counts down to 0 from the current location and replaces duplicates. Once that test passes, then you'll go to the next element, create a new random number, and then test the ones before it for duplicates.

I've done this here, and it's reduced the number of randomly generated numbers, but I still run into the stray duplicate:

```
import java.lang.Object;
    import java.util.Random;

public class Prog433a {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Random randslct = new Random();

        int[] list = new int[20];
        int counter = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int min2 = 0;


        System.out.println("\nAfter");

        for (int k = 0; k < list.length - 1; k++) {
            list [k] = randslct.nextInt(30) + 1;
            for (int z = list.length - 1; z >= 0; z--) {
                if (list[k] == list[z] && z!=k) {
                    while (list[k] == list[z]) {
                        list [k] = randslct.nextInt(30) + 1; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int min = list[0];
        while (counter < list.length - 1) {
            for (int x = 0; x < list.length - 1; x++) { // scroll through the indexes.
                if (list[x] < min) {
                    min = list[x];
                    index = x; // keep the index of the biggest number.
                } 
            }
            System.out.println(list[index]);
            min = 100 * (list[index]);

            list[index] = 100 * (list[index]); // change the value in the original array so it won't find the same max again
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

System Output:

```
After
2
5
6
10
11
12
13
15
16
17
19
22
22
24
25
27
28
29
29


After
1
2
2
4
5
7
8
9
10
13
15
16
21
24
25
26
28
29
30

After
1
2
3
5
6
7
11
12
13
14
15
16
18
21
22
25
26
27
29

After
2
3
3
4
6
10
12
14
15
16
17
20
22
23
24
25
26
27
30

After
7
8
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
17
18
19
20
21
23
24
27
29
30
```

I posted my output towards the bottom.
Because this is an introductory coding class, I'd prefer if the solution did not involve Sets or any of the like. But alas, beggars cannot be choosers.

Is there something I have forgotten to add?

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please?

Comment: IMHO, the java way is to create a Set with the possibly duplicated numbers, then add random numbers to it until it reach the wanted size or *better* to call nextInt and check if the result is in the list before adding the number to the list

Comment: Just a note, why do you import the `Object` class? Unless this is JDK 1.0, it is unnecessary. :)

Comment: @khelwood - Sorry, I'd posted this before class. I think I might have fixed the indentation, either that or someone else did.

Comment: @RC. I can understand that, but I guess I'd like to understand planning the algorithm before hitting up the Sets.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl -- My mistake! I didn't mean to do it. I might have imported it on accident while writing the code earlier.

Comment: @Nikolas I don't want to argue but I use Set on a almost-daily basis and arrays of int almost never. IMHO to learn java you have to learn the basic tools (i.e. what's in the SDK and how to leverage it for your need)

Comment: @RC. I have little knowledge on the professional uses of Java (and Java in general), so I cannot argue with you. However, I just know that my teacher wants to see what we've learned so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you detect a duplicate you generate a new number, but you never go back and check that the the newly generated number is not a duplicate of the numbers you already checked. When you run into a duplicate you'll need to reset the checking loop through some mechanism.

I fixed up the code to work around the problem, but it's not the prettiest solution. I also did some minor optimisation as you were looping through unnecessary indices.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Prog433a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random randslct = new Random();

        int[] list = new int[20];
        int counter = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int min2 = 0;

        System.out.println("\nAfter");

        for(int k = 0; k < list.length - 1; k++) {

            list[k] = randslct.nextInt(30) + 1;
            boolean unique = true;
            for(int z = k - 1; z >= 0; z--) {
                if(list[k] == list[z]) {
                    if(list[k] == list[z]) {
                        unique = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!unique) {
                // Repeat last index
                --k;
            }
        }

        int min = list[0];
        while(counter < list.length - 1) {
            for(int x = 0; x < list.length - 1; x++) { // scroll through the indexes.
                if(list[x] < min) {
                    min = list[x];
                    index = x; // keep the index of the biggest number.
                }
            }
            System.out.println(list[index]);
            min = 100 * (list[index]);

            list[index] = 100 * (list[index]); // change the value in the original array so it won't find the same max again
            counter++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Also a way. If OP doesn't know methods yet, this might be the superior answer.

Comment: Aah, thank you very much. I understood what the problem was, but I had no idea how to fix it--that is, how I could "rewind" the program to make it reiterate through the array of numbers again to assure that the randomly selected number made it out correctly. The idea of creating a boolean never hit me, but I'll definitely keep it in mind for future problems. I appreciate your help so much.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for asking so late, but what was the use of including the if(!unique)in the program? I don't know what that does--is that the part of the code that rewinds?

Comment: Basically that if branch wound back the index of the for loop by one if the selected random number was not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is when you try to add a new number. You just check, if it isn't the same as the one before, but not if it is the same as twice before. You can do this as follow:

```
boolean isDuplicate(int index, int[] list){
    for(int i=index-1; i>=0;i--){
        if(int[i]==int[index])
            return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

instead of your inner of the for-loop you can now write:

```
do{
    list[k] = randslct.nextInt(30) + 1;
}while(isDuplicate(k, list));
```

Also you should change your output, e.g. give the already written output a negative value and ignore negative values. If you want to change the numbers up to e.g. 200 your code now won't work.

Comment: Ohh, thank you. However, I haven't worked with methods that dealt specifically with arrays yet, so I don't know if using this answer would be practical for me to submit to my teacher. Thank you for your suggestion, though. I will certainly keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take this by example. Consider that the current list that has been generated is:

```
list = [5, 7, 9, 3, 8, 9]
```

where 9 is the current number.

Now in the for-loop, you iterate from list[6] to list[0]. Here, in comparision, you come to 2nd index (list[2]) where the condition

```
list[k] == list[z] && z != k
```

turns out to be true and a new random number is generated. Lets assume that here the new random number that you generated is '8'. The loop terminates successfully and your array now has a duplicate.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I think I had an inkling of what the problem was prior to posting, but not the knowledge to fix it. Thank you.